# How to save integer to sql column with data type int

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

i am having this problem for quite some time now and cannot figure out the solution..

i have a productid that i get as a result of sql query. The data type of productid in database is int

```
        Dim scheduleid As Integer

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into DeploymentSchedules (scheduleName) values('Schedule');select Scope_Identity();"
        scheduleid = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Now when i want to insert it into another table ...

```
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into 
  locationsSchedule(LocationName,length,width,height,floor,walls,permIeter,scheduleid)
  values('" + strRoomName + "','" + txtLength.Text + "','" + txtWidth.Text + "','" + 
  txtHeight.Text + "','" + wallSTring + "','" + floorString + "','" + perimeterStrin +
    "','" + scheduleid + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

I am having error

```
       Conversion from string "Insert into locationsSchedule(Lo" to type 'Double'
       is not valid.
```

I know it has something to do with integer as when i remove product id it is working .Please help

THank you

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `'` around your `scheduleid` which will cast the int to string. Remove them and all should be fine (maybe you have to do this for other columns also):

```
"'," + scheduleid + ")"
```

BTW: Ever heard of [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)?

Comment: Sony Pictures hadn't! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does changing from

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

to

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

remove the error for you?

In your first example you are returning the recently created unique id for the row. In the second query you're not. Either change as shown here or return an integer from your query.

Oh, and look at other ways of building SQL strings (parametrised queries!)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@schedule", SqlDbType.BigInt, scheduleid) STILL NO LUCK  
This error occur on executin query

The parameterized query '(@schedule bigint)Insert into locationsSchedule(LocationName,len' expects the parameter '@schedule', which was not supplied.

Comment: Try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schedule",scheduleid)